# bootstrap responsive import fails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I am trying to upgrade my gem to install `Bootstrap 3.0.` So I put in my gem

```
gem 'anjlab-bootstrap-rails', :require => 'bootstrap-rails',
      git: "https://github.com/anjlab/bootstrap-rails.git"
```

In my `application.scss`, `@import "twitter/bootstrap;" works fine but when I add`import "twitter/bootstrap-responsive";` I get this

```
File to import not found or unreadable: twitter/bootstrap-responsive.
```

Could someone help ?

Comment: in Gem README I have not found that  `import  twitter/bootstrap-responsive ` they only use @import "twitter/bootstrap"; even as per https://gist.github.com/yury/5662144

Comment: @RajarshiDas but I found that `https://github.com/yury/anjlab-bootstrap-app`... do you mean `bootstrap-responsive` is not available ?

Comment: they did not mention anything on there README regarding `bootstrap-responsive` follow there better suggestion Follow there README